# Supressing "Undefined variable: variables in module_block_view()" without hiding the notice

Tags: 7, blocks, hooks

I tried to create a simple custom block inside a custom module. there is a notice that inform me about undefined variable, but the block rendered properly. I am not sure where the mistake in the code is, but any nudge in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

I know I can hide the error message by accessing `admin/config/development/logging` or by modules such as [Disable Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages), but that isn't what I desire since it essentially just hiding the problem under the rug and hiding other notices that I might be interested to look at.

**mymodule.module**

```
<?php
/**
* Declare what blocks are provided by this module
* Implements hook_block_info().
*/

function mymodule_block_info() {
  $block = array();

  $block['myblock1'] = array(
    'info' => t('Block number 1'),
  );

  $block['myblock2'] = array( 
    'info' => t('Block number 2'),
  );

  return $block;
}

/**
* Define what our block is going to look like.
* Implements hook_block_view().
*/

function mymodule_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'myblock1':
      $block['content'] = theme('myblock1', $variables);
      break;

    case 'myblock2':
      $block['content'] = theme('myblock2', $variables);
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}

/**
* Implementation of hook_theme().
*/

function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'myblock1' => array(
      'variables' => array(),
      'template' => 'templates/block--myblock1',
    ),

    'myblock2' => array(
      'variables' => array(),
      'template' => 'templates/block--myblock2',
    ),
  );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `$block['content'] = theme('myblock1', $variables);` and `$block['content'] = theme('myblock2', $variables);`: `mymodule_block_view()` doesn't define any `$variables` variable; just define it or use an array directly.

Since in `mymodule_theme()` you don't define any variable for your theme functions, just replace your `mymodule_block_view()` with the following one.

```
function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'myblock1':
      $block['content'] = theme('myblock1', array());
      break;

    case 'myblock2':
      $block['content'] = theme('myblock2', array());
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}
```

To make the question more complete: Drupal doesn't define any global `$variables` nor do `hook_block_view()` implementations receive any `$variables` as parameter. Therefore, `$variables` could just be a local variables for your function. That is why you are getting that error: You are using a variable without to first declare it.

Notice that if `$variables` were a global variable, you should still declare it as `global $variables` in your function, or use it as `$GLOBALS['variables']`. (Don't try it since it doesn't work because doesn't define any global variable with that name.)

Comment: Where is $variables defined

Comment: It is not defined.

Comment: "Notice that if `$variables` would be a global variable, you should declare it as global `$variables` in your function". So the scope of this variable will be in the function only, right?

Comment: To remove the error u can just declare it $variables=array ();

Comment: Exactly, but you function doesn't define any `$variables`; it passes it to `theme()` without declaring it. Since you need to use an empty array, just pass `array()` to `theme()` instead of `$variables` as you do.

Comment: @ShreyaShetty Yep. That worked. I also tried to remove the `$variables` as in `$block['content'] = theme('myblock1')` and it worked, as well.